# Proxy c# selenium

Tags: c#, proxy, selenium

Здравствуйте, нужен совет, есть программа написаная на с# есть ее исходний код, нужно чтобы программа работала так же но через прокси. Нужен метод именно указания прокси через программу, а не через сам бразуер так как прокси будет регулярно менятся и подгружатся с файла, но как это сделать я знаю, а вот как добавить эту функцию установки прокси в программу не знаю.

Прокси идут с авторизацией, так что нашел в гугле несколько решений, но не знаю как правилньо имплиментировать этот код в программу.

Нашел даже [пример на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186579/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-firefox-profile-using-proxy-with-authentication).

Так же  есть [пример для Gecko firefox](http://swblog.ru/articles/programming/modifikaciya-brauzera-ot-mozilla-v-c.html), но у меня обычный: 
Мой основной код:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;


namespace RPost
{
  public static class RotaPostWorker
  {
    public static WorkerAuthorizeAndRefsToTask _S1_Get_Task_Windows(InputInfo input, CurrentInfo current)
    {
      WorkerAuthorizeAndRefsToTask authorizeAndRefsToTask = new WorkerAuthorizeAndRefsToTask();
      LogSystem.ShowLogMessage("Запускаем окно браузера");
      IWebDriver rotapostBrowser = Settings.RotapostBrowser;

      try
      {
        string url1 = current.auth_info.Web;
        LogSystem.ShowLogMessage("Переходим на ссылку " + current.auth_info.Web);
        rotapostBrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url1);
```

Но не совсем понимаю куда я должен вставлять участок кода с stackoverflow все время выдаются разные ошикибю, может сначала нужно подключить еще какую-то библиотеку.
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что кусок кода с StackOverflow можно просто так бездумно вставить в программу, и она заработает? Почему бы вам не разобраться, что именно этот кусок делает?

Comment: нет, я знаю что так нельзя поєтому и написал сюда, тот кусок кода редактирует профиль фаерфокс устанавливая прокси

Comment: обнаружил что мне даже не нужно каждый раз менять сам прокси, осталось узнать как можно только задавать логин и пароль какие команды использовать на языке c# для указания данных в сплывающее окно

Answer (score 4):

1. Селениум гипер паршиво работает с прокси. Не просто паршиво, а гипер паршиво. **Считай что такой возоможности в фаярфоксе или хроме просто тупо нету.** Я довольно неплохо с селениумом разобрался, но на это я потратил несколько дней и так и не разобрался. Даже видел на фриланс бирже предложение заплатить 50 баксов показать девелоперу как это обойти т.к. он неделю пытался сам разобратся.(при чем он вообще уточнял: "если вы не делали это раньше, не хватайтесь за даную работу. Я сам дев с большим стажем и разобратся так и не смог")
2. Но это работает с phantomJS. Вот пример кода:

v

```
var userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";

var currDirr = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "phantomjs.exe";

string proxyHostStr = string.Format("{0}:{1}", proxyHost, proxyPort);
string proxyAuth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", proxyLogin, proxyPassword);

var serviceJs = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    serviceJs.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    serviceJs.SslProtocol = "tlsv1";
    serviceJs.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
    serviceJs.LoadImages = false;

    serviceJs.AddArguments("--proxy=" + proxyHostStr, "--proxy-type=http", "--proxy-auth=" + proxyAuth);

var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);

Instance = new PhantomJSDriver(serviceJs, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

таким макаром вполне возможно запустить браузер с прокси с помощью селениума. Хоть это будет и phantomJS. Но нужно иметь ввиду что с ним могут быть связано много проблем т.к. движок. все же, не такой как у хрома или лисы. И сайты под этот движок не всегда заточены.